# UPDATE record with subquery into own table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a calendar table, that I'm trying to use to deal with some weekend and holiday issues.

The structure is simple:

```
CREATE TABLE calendar
(
    daterank INT,
    thedate DATE
);
```

The idea is that every record has a daterank, that is used for comparison purposes. Non-holiday weekdays have incremental dateranks, weekends and holidays have a daterank equal to the immediately preceding non-holiday weekday.

Setting daterank for non-holiday weekdays turned out to be easier than I thought it would be, but setting the weekends and holidays is more complicated than I thought it would be.

A subset of the data:

```
daterank    thedate

881         2013-05-21
882         2013-05-22
883         2013-05-23
884         2013-05-24
NULL        2013-05-25
NULL        2013-05-26
885         2013-05-27
886         2013-05-28
887         2013-05-29
888         2013-05-30
889         2013-05-31
NULL        2013-06-01
```

What I want, in the above case, is to replace the NULLs for 5/25 and 5/26 with 884 (the value for 5/24), the NULL for 6/1 with 889, etc.

What doesn't work:

```
UPDATE calendar c1
SET c1.daterank = (
    SELECT MAX(c2.daterank)
    FROM calendar c2
    WHERE c2.thedate < c1.thedate
    AND c2.daterank IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE daterank IS NULL
;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: So you have a calendar table to deal with holiday issues and you don't indicate whether or not the date is a holiday?  How very odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not use an alias for the table you want to update.

```
UPDATE calendar 
SET daterank = (
    SELECT MAX(c2.daterank)
    FROM calendar c2
    WHERE c2.thedate < calendar.thedate
    AND c2.daterank IS NOT NULL
)
WHERE daterank IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the result:

```
;with cte as
(
  select daterank, thedate
  from calendar
  where daterank is null
) 
update c
set c.daterank = d.daterank
from cte c
cross apply
(
  select top 1 daterank, thedate
  from calendar d
  where d.thedate < c.thedate
    and d.daterank is not null
  order by daterank desc
) d;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef4ff/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a quirky update, I believe this should work:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_Cal ON calendar (daterank)
GO

DECLARE @Prev_Dt_Rank BIGINT

UPDATE  calendar
SET     daterank =  CASE WHEN daterank IS NULL THEN @Prev_Dt_Rank
                                             ELSE daterank
                                        END                                                                                                                                                         
        ,@Prev_Dt_Rank = daterank
FROM    calendar
WITH (TABLOCKX)
OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
GO
```

The index is essential, and the first daterank can't be NULL.
Some have an aversion to the quirky update, but in a situation like this it's trivial to ensure it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt ;)

```
;WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT t.r, t.d
    FROM t 
   WHERE t.r IS NOT NULL
)
, tbl AS
(
  SELECT
    (
      SELECT cte.r
        FROM cte
       WHERE cte.d = (SELECT MAX(sub.d)
                        FROM cte sub
                       WHERE sub.d <= t.d)
    ) AS r,
    t.d
  FROM t 
)

UPDATE t
   SET t.r = tbl.r
  FROM t
  JOIN tbl ON tbl.d = t.d
 WHERE t.r IS NULL

SELECT * FROM t
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19b4b2/10)